# How do you connect to a TFS server in C# using specific credentials?

Tags: c#, authentication, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am attempting to write a c# application that connects to TFS and retrieves work item information.  Unfortunately, it seems like all examples of using the TFS SDK are using the default credentials for the current user (i.e. my domain login information).  The closest piece of information I found is to use the `TeamFoundationServer (String, ICredentials)` constructor, however I cannot find any information for a suitable class that interfaces with the `ICredentials` interface (especially since it seems to not be using the System.Net ICredentials but a TeamFoundationServer specific ICredentials).

Does anyone have any insight for logging into TFS with a specific username/password/domain combination?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following code should help you:

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfs:8080/tfs", cred);
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Domain is either the actual domain, or in a Workgroup situation, it would be the name of the server that hosts the TFS Application Tier.

Comment: Note that `TeamFoundationServer` has been deprecated in favor of `TfsConfigurationServer`, but this code is valid for it too.

Answer (score 14):

For TFS 2015 & 2017, objects and methods mentioned have been (or are being) deprecated.

To connect to TFS using specific credentials:

```
// For TFS 2015 & 2017

// Ultimately you want a VssCredentials instance so...
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(@"user.name", @"Password1", "DOMAIN");
WindowsCredential winCred = new WindowsCredential(netCred);
VssCredentials vssCred = new VssClientCredentials(winCred);

// Bonus - if you want to remain in control when
// credentials are wrong, set 'CredentialPromptType.DoNotPrompt'.
// This will thrown exception 'TFS30063' (without hanging!).
// Then you can handle accordingly.
vssCred.PromptType = CredentialPromptType.DoNotPrompt;

// Now you can connect to TFS passing Uri and VssCredentials instances as parameters
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(@"http://tfs:8080/tfs");
var tfsTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, vssCred);

// Finally, to make sure you are authenticated...
tfsTeamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Comment: FYI pull in `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` from Nuget.

Answer (score 4):

Years down the line, this is how you do it with TFS 2013 API:

```
// Connect to TFS Work Item Store
ICredentials networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(tfsUsername, tfsPassword, domain);
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(@"http://my-server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, networkCredential);
WorkItemStore witStore = new WorkItemStore(tfs);
```

---

If that doesn't work, try to pass the credentials through other `Credential` classes (worked for me):

```
// Translate username and password to TFS Credentials
ICredentials networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(tfsUsername, tfsPassword, domain);
WindowsCredential windowsCredential = new WindowsCredential(networkCredential);
TfsClientCredentials tfsCredential = new TfsClientCredentials(windowsCredential, false);

// Connect to TFS Work Item Store
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(@"http://my-server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, tfsCredential);
WorkItemStore witStore = new WorkItemStore(tfs);
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the `NetworkCredential` straight to the `TfsTeamProjectCollection`, instead of creating two unnecessary objects?

Comment: Well, I tried that, and I was getting the infamous `Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server` error. Even after clearing my Windows Credential Manager entries it was still happening. Then I experimented a bit until this made it work. Maybe you're right and you don't need it :-) Just wanted to save someone else the trouble

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - that's unexpected, so I'll make sure that we look into it.

Comment: @EdwardThomson thank you for your time. I can confirm using the NetworkCredential directly *does* work now. I honestly don't know why it didn't in the first place. My Credential Manager only had an entry for `virtualapp/didlogical` (Windows Live) and some local servers. I removed all of them anyway. I know I was trying other classes like `BasicAuthCredential`; maybe I just used the wrong credential type from the get go? Anyway, I'm adding an edit to my answer. Keep well!