# Can not connect to Team Foundation Service data source for coded ui tests

Tags: datasource, coded-ui-tests, azure-devops

When running Coded UI Tests locally on my machine that have parameterized values in the Test Cases stored in Team Foundation Service, I get the error:

> The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read
>   the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see
>   "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests"
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
>   Error details: TF30064: You are not authorized to access the server.

This is the data source attribute for the test method

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "https://*accountname*.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection;*project*", "628", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

I don't have all permissions in tfs, but I have most of them and any that should be relevant to the build service.

Comment: Looks like this was asked and dealt with on the MSDN Forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/417aff76-56c2-464b-a919-839dfdaf17ad

Comment: Yes that was my question on there. The "answer" was to email the Microsoft employee a screenshot of my permissions to which I did not get a response. Shortly after though, we upgraded to VS 2012 and the problem went away. Not sure why VS 2010 couldn't access TFS DataSources from Test Cases, but it isn't an issue in 2012.

Comment: @jjthemachine did you manage to solve it?