# How to create a Feedback Response in C#

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to add a feedback mechanism in my software.

It's a good idea to get the required information for a TFS `Feedback Response` from the user and then create a TFS work item for it.

So my clear question would be:

**Question:** How can I add a 'Feedback Response' work item given its `Title`, `Description`, `Team Project` and `Team Server` using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite straightforward:

```
var cred = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password", "Domain");
var tfs = 
    new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("YourServerUrl/Collection"), cred);
var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
var workItemTypes = workItemStore.Projects["ProjectName"].WorkItemTypes;
var workItemType = workItemTypes["Feedback Response"];
var workItem = new WorkItem(workItemType);

workItem.Title = "Feedback Response 1";
workItem.Description = "Totally awesome piece of software!";
workItem.Save();
```

> Domain is either the actual domain, or in a Workgroup situation, it would be the name of the server that hosts the TFS Application Tier.[<sup>Source</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150730/2974754)

Answer is based on the article [TFS 2010 API - Create WorkItems(Bugs)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3280.tfs-2010-api-create-workitems-bugs.aspx) and tested on VS 2013 + TFS 2013.