# Connect to TFS using credentials in C#

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to connect to TFS using:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection 
  = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
```

but with credentials. For example I want to connect to "http://tfs.mydomain.com/sandbox/" with credentials "myusername" and "mypassword"...what is the correct way to set up credentials for this?

After getting connected using the credentials I know how to do everything else i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NetworkCredential class implements the ICredentials interface and will allow you to authenticate against AD.

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
```

Pass the NetworkCredential object as part of your constructor.

See here for more information on the new constructor you must call: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff737302.aspx

Best practice nowadays is to use TfsClientCredentials class, which would look like this:

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(cred);
TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
```

Personally I've always just used the NetworkCredential.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN talks about using credentials to connect to TFS [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx#authenticatedcredentials):

> You can use an ICredentials object when you connect to Team Foundation
>   Server to specify the identity to impersonate. This strategy does not
>   require special permissions, but you must be able to obtain the
>   password of the identity to create the ICredentials object.
>
> You can also specify an implementation of ICredentialsProvider when you
>   connect to Team Foundation Server to handle requests for new
>   credentials. The system calls the implementation of
>   ICredentialsProvider that you specify to request new credentials when
>   the credentials that are specified by the ICredentials object are not
>   successfully authenticated or authorized to perform the operation.
>
> To prompt the user for credentials, you can use the UICredentialsProvider
>   class, which implements ICredentialsProvider by displaying a logon
>   dialog box to prompt the user for new credentials.

**EDIT**: Dig some more reading and the new, most correct way to do this is to use

`TfsClientCredentials`

which is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsclientcredentials.aspx)

Comment: I don't really see where you set the credentials you are using in TfsClientCredentials...like how do I set the password and username?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130172(v=vs.90).aspx  this article explains it, and if you want take a look at a good project using tfs https://taskcardcreator.codeplex.com/  is a great sample of things that could be done with it.    and there is also this answer here at stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150260/how-do-you-connect-to-a-tfs-server-in-c-sharp-using-specific-credentials